# Date manipulation query conversion from mysql to postgres

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have such query in mysql

`SELECT DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 12-MONTH(NOW()) MONTH)), INTERVAL 3 year)`

I'm having hard time in my brain to convert this into postgres syntax. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What does this code doe?

Answer (score 0):

DATE_SUB is a MySQL function that does not exist in PostgreSQL.

In PostgreSQL you can use , in your example something like:

```
SELECT (now() -INTERVAL  '3' Year) ::date;
```

There is no function equivalent to LAST_DAY() in PostgreSQL  as well, but you can use:

```
SELECT (date_trunc('MONTH', now()) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day')::date;
```

In MySQL,

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 12-MONTH(NOW()) MONTH)), INTERVAL 3 year) as new_date;
```

would give `2019-12-31`.

In PostgreSQL ,

```
SELECT ((date_trunc('MONTH', now()) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day') - (INTERVAL  '3' Year))::date ;
```

would give `2019-12-31`.

[MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/2zMM5MaU)

[PostgreSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/CDTqQseI)

Comment: Thank you this helped me to achieve the full result.


`SELECT ((DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', now()) + interval '1 MONTH - 1 DAY' + (12 - EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE)) * INTERVAL '1 MONTH') - (INTERVAL  '3' Year))::date ;`